# Getting list of solutions in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am learning prolog and I am reading a book called Programming Prolog for Artificial Intelligence. As practice I want to learn how to extend one of the examples in this book. Can someone please help?

Say you have these facts:

```
parent(pam, bob). %pam is a parent of bob
parent(george, bob). %george is a parent of bob
```

How would I write a prolog predicate that would give me a list of bobs parents? For example:

```
list_parents(bob, L).

L = [pam, george] ;
L = [george, pam] ;
true.
```

Answer (score 21):

An all-solutions predicate like `findall/3` might do the trick:

```
list_parents(P, L) :-
    findall(Parent, parent(Parent, P), L).
```

Simply put, `findall/3` finds all bindings for `Parent` in the 'backtrack-able' goal `parent(Parent, P)`, and puts all bindings of `Parent` into the list `L`. Note that this won't remove duplicates, but you can do a `sort/2` to `L` before returning it to create a set. Executing this:

```
?- list_parents(bob, L).
L = [pam, george].
```

If you don't have `findall/3` in your PROLOG implementation, you could do it manually like this:

```
list_parents(P, L) :-
    list_parents(P, [], L).

list_parents(P, Acc, L) :-
    parent(Parent, P),
    \+ member(Parent, Acc), !,
    list_parents(P, [Parent|Acc], L). 
list_parents(_, L, L).
```

This version sends calls to `list_parents/2` off to an accumulator-version, `list_parents/3`. The latter tries to collect `Parent` bindings also, as long as we haven't seen them before (hence the `\+ member` check), and returns the list where no new `Parent` bindings accumulated into the `Acc` list can be found. Executing this gives us the same result as the first option:

```
?- list_parents(bob, L).
L = [pam, george].
```

Comment: `findall`, that's what I was trying to Google for

Comment: sharky, your findall implementation doesn't account for repeated elements. If you have this in the database:
    `parent(hannah,carl).
    parent(hannah,carl).
    parent(bob,carl).`
your rule outputs [hannah,bob]. But if you try with findall you get [hannah,hannah,bob]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
parent(pam, bob). %pam is a parent of bob
parent(george, bob). %george is a parent of bob
list_parents(A, Es, [X|Xs]) :- parent(X, A), \+ member(X, Es), list_parents(A, [X|Es], Xs).
list_parents(A, Es, []).
```

That was an inefficient method, a better method will need a "solutions" higher-order predicate.

list_parents(X, Ys) :- solutions(parent, [X, W], 1, Ys)

Comment: I posted a follow up question to your answer regarding the "solutions" predicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47233986/higher-order-solutions-predicate