# higher-order "solutions" predicate

Tags: prolog, lambda-prolog

I am using a higher order Prolog variant that lacks `findall`.

There is another question on implementing our own `findall` here: [Getting list of solutions in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191038/getting-list-of-solutions-in-prolog).

The inefficient implementation is:

```
parent(pam, bob). %pam is a parent of bob
parent(george, bob). %george is a parent of bob

list_parents(A, Es, [X|Xs]) :-
   parent(X, A),
   \+ member(X, Es),
   list_parents(A, [X|Es], Xs).
list_parents(A, Es, []).
```

The efficient one

> need a "solutions" higher-order predicate:

```
list_parents(X, Ys) :- solutions(parent, [X, W], 1, Ys)
```

What is `solutions`? Can I implement my own `solutions` predicate in higher order lambda Prolog?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, if `findall/3` were not available, you could implement it for example via the **dynamic database**.

For example, for the concrete use case of parents:

```
list_parents(_) :-
        parent(P, _),
        assertz(parent(P)),
        false.
list_parents(Ps) :-
        phrase(retract_parents, Ps).

retract_parents -->
        (   { retract(parent(P)) } ->
            [P],
            retract_parents
        ;   []
        ).
```

Sample query:

```
?- list_parents(Ps).
Ps = [pam, george].
```

You can combine this with `sort/2` for asymptotically optimal performance, avoiding the quadratic overhead of the "naive" solution to remove duplicates.

**Beware** though: First, this is *not thread-safe*. To make it thread-safe you need to add more information pertaining to the current thread.

Second, if you implement full-fledged `findall/3` in this way, you must take care of *nested* `findall/3` calls.

One way to do this is to assert two *kinds* of terms:

- `solution(S)`, such as `solution(parent(pam))`, indicating a concrete solution that was found on backtracking via the most recent `findall/3` call
- `mark`, indicating that a new `findall/3` starts here

When collecting solutions, you only proceed to the most recent `mark`.

See Richard O'Keefe's book for a good introduction to these issues.

Comment: Does it make sense to reflect the order of solutions found?

Answer (score 3):

If your Prolog has some kind of non backtrackable assignment, like SWI-Prolog ['global' variables](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=gvar), you could implement (beware, simple minded code) in this way:

```
:- meta_predicate solutions(0, ?).
:- meta_predicate solutions(+, 0, ?).

solutions(G, L) :-
    solutions(G, G, L).

solutions(P, G, L) :-
    ( nb_current(solutions_depth, C) -> true ; C=1 ),
    D is C+1,
    nb_setval(solutions_depth, D),
    atom_concat(solutions_depth_, D, Store),
    nb_setval(Store, []),
    (   G,
        nb_getval(Store, T),
        nb_setval(Store, [P|T]),
        fail
    ;   nb_getval(Store, R)
    ),
    nb_delete(Store),
    nb_setval(solutions_depth, C),
    reverse(R, L).
```

Usage of 'global' variables results in more efficient execution WRT the dynamic database (assert/retract), and (in SWI-prolog) can be used even in multithreaded applications.

*edit*

Thanks to @false comment, moved the cut(s) *before* reverse/2, and introduced a stack for reentrant calls: for instance

```
?- solutions(X-Ys,(between(1,3,X),solutions(Y,between(1,5,Y),Ys)),S).
S = [1-[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2-[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3-[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]].
```

*edit*

Here is a variant of solutions/3, building the result list in order, to avoid the final reverse/2 call. Adding results to the list tail is a bit tricky...

```
solutions(P, G, L) :-
    ( nb_current(solutions_depth, C) -> true ; C=1 ),
    D is C+1,
    nb_setval(solutions_depth, D),
    atom_concat(solutions_depth_, D, Store),
    (   G,
        ( nb_current(Store, U/B) -> B = [P|R], Q = U/R ; Q = [P|T]/T ),
        nb_setval(Store, Q),
        fail
    ;   ( nb_current(Store, L/[]) -> true ; L = [] )
    ),
    nb_delete(Store),
    nb_setval(solutions_depth, C).
```